# Understanding scoring results - exact scores lower than partial

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, n-gram

I understand the Lucene Explain feature is not implemented for Azure Search and you can vote for it here if you want: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/7379515-support-explain-api

Here is my index that I created

```
{
  "name": "fieldvalue38gram",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "FieldValueID",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": false,
      "key": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": false,
      "sortable": false,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "FieldID",
      "type": "Edm.Int32",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "sortable": false,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Text",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": true,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": "whitespace",
      "indexAnalyzer": null,
      "searchAnalyzer": null,
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    },
    {
      "name": "partialName",
      "type": "Edm.String",
      "facetable": false,
      "filterable": true,
      "retrievable": false,
      "searchable": true,
      "sortable": true,
      "analyzer": null,
      "indexAnalyzer": "ingram",
      "searchAnalyzer": "whitespace",
      "synonymMaps": [],
      "fields": []
    }
  ],
  "suggesters": [],
  "scoringProfiles": [
    {
      "name": "exactFirst",
      "text": {
        "weights": {
          "Text": 2,
          "partialName": 1
        }

      }
    }
  ],
  "defaultScoringProfile": "",
  "corsOptions": null,
  "analyzers": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "name": "ingram",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "tokenFilters": [ "lowercase", "NGramTokenFilter" ],
      "charFilters": []
    }
  ],
  "charFilters": [],
  "tokenFilters": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.NGramTokenFilterV2",
      "name": "NGramTokenFilter",
      "minGram": 3,
      "maxGram": 8
    }
  ],
  "tokenizers": []
}
```

When I query using search=black

```
indexes/fieldvalue38gram/docs?api-version={{version}}&scoringProfile=exactFirst&$top=21&search=black
```

I end up getting

```
{
    "@search.score": 4.051315,
    "FieldValueID": "167402",
    "FieldID": 8,
    "Text": "BLACKSMITH",
    "partialName": "BLACKSMITH"
},
{
    "@search.score": 3.9905946,
    "FieldValueID": "18594",
    "FieldID": 8,
    "Text": "BLACK",
    "partialName": "BLACK"
},
```

which is not what I would expect.

I should get a boost for exact match. In addition, reading through documentation, I see that length plays a part in the scoring meaning shorter text gets a higher score during indexing.

With this in mind I don't understand why the second result would scored lower than the first.

- Can anyone explain the scoring in this scenario?
- Is there anything I can do to help understand the scoring?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

**2019-10-24**
Here is an example of what I've been battling with the scoring.  The 1st and 3rd entry are identical other than the doc id (FieldValueID).  I can find no rhyme or reason for the difference in the score.

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 0.10707458,
            "FieldValueID": "2",
            "FieldID": 2,
            "Text": "Another Brown2Black Cow"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.021882897,
            "FieldValueID": "4",
            "FieldID": 2,
            "Text": "Brown"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.017285194,
            "FieldValueID": "7",
            "FieldID": 2,
            "Text": "Another Brown2Black Cow"
        }
    ]
}
```

**2019-10-25**
Just found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture#scoring-in-a-distributed-index

and this **Note** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-capacity-planning#partition-and-replica-combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that its because you are forcing the TEXT field to use the whitespace analyzer rather than using the default analyzer. I don't believe the whitespace analyzer will lowercase your terms. Since your search query and your TEXT field contain different casing, I'm not sure they'd match. You can try it out by trying the search with a different casing and see what is being returned (same for the search analyzer, I'd recommend against simply using the whitespace analyzer there too).

Comment: I added another custom analyzer "lowercase", "whitespace" and it did fix the issue with scoring.  Any thoughts on HOW to analyze scores?  You also mentioned not using whitespace analyzer.  Why not and and what would be better?

Comment: As of now we unfortunately don't expose any API to help you understand the score themselves (we are working on it). However, in your case, you could have used the "Analyze text" api to understand how your content is being transformed into tokens:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer

Comment: The whitespace analyzer is just meant to break down your texts into tokens at every whitespace. If your goal is full text search, we have some more elaborate analyzers that will do more complex tokenization (such as stemming each words, accent folding, etc.)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-analyzers.
For example, if you know your text is in english, you could use the "en.microsoft" analyzer

Comment: I'm looking to implement autocomplete/suggester but using partial words, so those 2 options are out.  I have 10's of Millions of documents of unique data.  I would like to find 'hello world' if I search for 'ell'.   This leads me to n-grams.  I would like to give preference to more complete matches.  If I understand in my 'ingram' analyzer I should use 'en.microsoft'.